# cakephp htmlhelper

Tags: cakephp

I have to create a form like this:

Name:
Enter your name.

I am using the "before", "after" and "between" form-option in cakephp but it gives me an error.

Below is my code in cakephp.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('Post.title', 
    array( 
        'before' => array('label' => array(
                    'class' => 'thingy',
                    'text' => 'Title :'
                )
            ),
            'after' => array(
                'label' => array(
                    'class' => 'thingy',
                    'text' => 'Title :'
                )
            ),
            'between' => array(
                'id' => 'posttitle', 
                'size' => '50', 
                'maxlength' => '255', 
                'error' => false,
                'class'=>'field'
            )
    )
);
```

Comment: "it gives error" - please elaborate.

Comment: Please be specific... what error its throwing?

Comment: Please use proper intendation & clear description of your issue next time, edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code using for same  purpose

```
$this->Form->input('Post.title', 
                        array(
                            'placeholder' => 'Place holder name',
                            'value' => '', 
                            'class' => 'required',
                            'after'=>'</div>', 
                            'error' => false,
                            'between' => '<div class="controls extend-controls">',
                            'label' => array('class' => 'control-label extend_label', 'text' =>  $type.' '.$label_name.'<span class="red">*</span>'),
                            'div' => array('class' => 'control-group')
                            )
                        );
```

Hope this will help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Form->input('name', 
                    array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Your name',
                        'class' => 'required',
                        'label'=>false, 
                        'div' => false,
                        )
                    );
```

You need not div use div false inside array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Form->input('Post.title', array (
    'placeholder' => 'Enter Your Name',
    'class' => 'required',
    'label'=>false, 
    'div' => false
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouln't use arrays. It's Just a string parameters

> $options['before'], $options['between'], $options['separator'], and $options['after']
>
> Use these keys if you need to inject some markup inside the output of
>   the input() method:

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
'before' => '--before--',
'after' => '--after--',
'between' => '--between---'
));
```

Output:

```
<div class="input">
--before--
<label for="UserField">Field</label>
--between---
<input name="data[User][field]" type="text" value="" id="UserField" />
--after--
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use [] instead of array.

Comment: That's just a different syntax for the same thing. It makes no difference at all which one you use. The only difference is that `[]` will not work on older PHP versions.